# Windows Batch File: restore mysql database from dump file which name start with

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, restore

This is the way to restore a mysql database from command line:

```
       mysql -u username -pPASSWORD database_name < file-20140410.sql
```

But imagine that I don't know the name of the file, just I know that starts with "file-" and the extension is ".sql"

but this doesn't work:

```
      //this doesn't work
       mysql -u username -pPASSWORD database_name < file-*.sql
```

I need dump I database knowing only the begin of the filename.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the file, search in a CMD-window. Go to each drive, change to root directory and search for the file, i.e:

```
REM change drive letter
C:
REM change current directory to root directory
CD \
REM search your file in all subdirectories
DIR file-*.sql /s
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end thanks to "esac" it is SOLVED, but with some small changes. This is the final script:

```
 forfiles /m file-*.sql /c "cmd /c mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD database_name < @file"
```

Comment: You should mark my answer as complete if it helped you. If it didn't then no worries.

Answer (score -1):

Use `forfiles` command to use wildcards and perform an action on each file.

```
c:\test>forfiles /m file-*.sql /c "mysql -u username -pPASSWORD database_name ^< @file"
```